# Oracle SQL UPDATEXML Replace node value even if it's empty

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, updatexml

I have one CLOB database column which contain a big XML : XML_CONF
I usually use the function updateXML to modify specific node of the XML, it works great. But today, I have a lot of trouble with it, because the nodes I want to modify are sometimes empty, and it does not work in this case...

Example of XML with empty textValue :

```
<ns2:ConfigurationTree xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="com.xxxx.yyyy">
<ns2:ConfigurableProduct ...>...
    <ns2:CPNode name="cpX">...
        <ns2:FormProperty name="fpX">
            <ns2:SingleValuation isCommentUserChoice="false" isValueUserChoice="false" isQtyUserChoice="false">
                <ns2:Value>
                    **<ns2:textValue/>**
                </ns2:Value>
            </ns2:SingleValuation>
        </ns2:FormProperty>
    </ns2:CPNode>
</ns2:ConfigurableProduct>
```

Example of XML with textValue :

```
<ns2:ConfigurationTree xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="com.xxxx.yyyy">
<ns2:ConfigurableProduct ...>...
    <ns2:CPNode name="cpX">...
        <ns2:FormProperty name="fpX">
            <ns2:SingleValuation isCommentUserChoice="false" isValueUserChoice="false" isQtyUserChoice="false">
                <ns2:Value>
                    **<ns2:textValue>123456</ns2:textValue>**
                </ns2:Value>
            </ns2:SingleValuation>
        </ns2:FormProperty>
    </ns2:CPNode>
</ns2:ConfigurableProduct>
```

For example, to replace the textValue content by "78910", I tried this to handle the two cases :

```
update T_TABLE set XML_CONF = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
'//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue',xmltype('<textValue>78910</textValue>'),
'//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue/text()','78910',
'xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="xxxx.yyyy"').getClobVal();
```

But the result broke the XML (no more prefix and xmlns empty in node) :

```
<ns2:ConfigurationTree xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="com.xxxx.yyyy">
<ns2:ConfigurableProduct ...>...
    <ns2:CPNode name="cpX">...
        <ns2:FormProperty name="fpX">
            <ns2:SingleValuation isCommentUserChoice="false" isValueUserChoice="false" isQtyUserChoice="false">
                <ns2:Value>
                    **<textValue xmlns="">78910</textValue>**
                </ns2:Value>
            </ns2:SingleValuation>
        </ns2:FormProperty>
    </ns2:CPNode>
</ns2:ConfigurableProduct>
```

And if I recall the same request, with a different textValue, it does not update nothing anymore after that... I think it's because the prefix is broken on the node...

I try to do it with XMLQuery (Oracle 12), but it's the same problem.

**EDIT**

It almost works with :

```
    update T_TABLE set XML_CONF = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue/text()','78910',
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue[not(text())]',xmltype('<textValue>78910</textValue>'),
  xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="xxxx.yyyy"' ).getClobVal();
```

But in output I don't have the new ns2:textValue node, I only have :

```
<ns2:Value><textValue xmlns="">78910</textValue></ns2:Value>
```

Why does it break the ns2 prefix, and why it put an empty xmlns attribute ?

If I specify the namespace in the new node it works, but it seems useless because they are already declared in the root node :

```
    update T_TABLE set XML_CONF = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue/text()','78910',
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue[not(text())]',xmltype('<ns2:textValue xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="xxxx.yyyy">78910</ns2:textValue>'),
  'xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="xxxx.yyyy"' ).getClobVal();
```

Give :

```
<ns2:textValue xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="xxxx.yyyy">78910</ns2:textValue></ns2:Value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
update T_TABLE set XML_CONF = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
  '//ns2:FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//ns2:Value/ns2:textValue/text()','78910',
  '//ns2:FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//ns2:Value/ns2:textValue[not(text())]',
     xmlelement("ns2:textValue", xmlattributes('com.xxxx' as "xmlns:ns2"), '78910'),
  'xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="com.xxxx.yyyy"').getClobVal();
```

to identify either a text node or a node with no text; or if `ns2` is the same as the default (from comments):

```
update T_TABLE set XML_CONF = updatexml(xmltype(XML_CONF),
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue/text()','78910',
  '//FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//Value/textValue[not(text())]',
     xmlelement("ns2:textValue", xmlattributes('com.xxxx' as "xmlns:ns2"), '78910'),
  'xmlns:ns2="com.xxxx" xmlns="com.xxxx"').getClobVal();
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b794e5f95f1e7c4af17e369732035535) with your real namespace. The newly-created `textValue` node redeclares `ns2` but functionally that shouldn't matter.

Of course, updateXML is deprecated in 12c, but you should be able to do the same thing with Xquery update. In fact that's simpler:

```
update t_table set xml_conf = xmlquery(
   'copy $d := .
    modify (
      for $i in $d//*:FormProperty[@name="fpX"]//*:Value/*:textValue
        return replace value of node $i with $newValue
    )
    return $d'
    passing xmltype(xml_conf), '78910' as "newValue"
    returning content
  ).getClobVal();
```

I've wildcarded the namespaces for simplicity (well, actually, I haven't figure out how to make it work with namespace prefixes, even if `ns2` is different from default). For some reason that gets "ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: XQuery Update connot be compiled" on both db<>fiddle and SQL Fiddle, which are both 11.20.02; but works fine on my 11.2.0.4 and 12.2.0.1 databases.

You can add a check for the relevant node existing to avoid unneccessary updates.

Comment: Weird, it did not work :/
After the two requests, the XML is still empty :

Comment: <ns2:FormProperty name="fpCodeActiviteArty">
<ns2:Description>fpCodeActiviteArty</ns2:Description>
<ns2:SystemProperties valuationType="Single" type="Text"/>
<ns2:Status updateable="true"/>
<ns2:ValueStatus computed="true" failed="false"/>
<ns2:QuantityStatus exist="false" />
<ns2:CommentStatus computed="false" failed="false"/>
<ns2:SingleValuation isQtyUserChoice="false">
<ns2:Value>
<ns2:textValue/>
</ns2:Value>
</ns2:SingleValuation>
</ns2:FormProperty>

Comment: It works in the fiddle with your sample. I have no idea what you are doing differently, I can't see the original XML or the actual update you are doing. Maybe your `ns2` definition doesn't quite match or something, that would silently do nothing. But that's just a guess obviously.

Comment: I modify the fiddle here to put the entire XML, but the string is too long : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a6e883d13d05f1b86b5c3f807a6e1ac

The name of the formProperty I cant to modify is : name="fpCodeActiviteArty"
Also, I just see that even if your solutions works, in the case of an empty textValue node, it does not keep the <textValue>XXX</textValue>, it put directly the value "78910" like that <value>78910</value>.

Comment: In fact, if I just put the real declaration of namespace in my samples in your fiddle here, it does not work anymore : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ebfc462cfe76bf15149d606a58095d5

Comment: I edited the original post, your solution almost works but I have a "Déjà vu" problem with the new textValue node created, no ns2 prefix, and an empty xmlns attribute... Thanks !

Comment: My fiddle didn't work with your real namespace because the default is the same path as `ns2`; I wondered why your question didn't specify `ns2:` in the updateXML call. Yeah, I missed that the Value was set instead of textValue. [This is as close as I can get at the moment](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b794e5f95f1e7c4af17e369732035535). Redeclaring the `ns2` in the new element is ugly but valid.

Comment: I've added an XMLQuery update version that doesn't duplicate the namespace declaration.

Comment: Great, the last proposition works perfectly ! Thank you